# How to force unmount a partition

Tags: mount

How can I `umount` a partition on my Linux system by force? Normally I would just type `sudo umount /dev/<Device>` but if the device is busy it returns

```
 umount: <Mount Location>: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
```

How can I force `umount`?

Answer (score 5):

You don't. That message is there for a reason. Something is currently using the partition so force unmounting it can lead to data corruption. So, the first thing you do is check what is using the partition:

```
$ sudo umount mountpoint
umount: /home/pi/mountpoint: target is busy
        (In some cases useful info about processes that
         use the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1).)
```

OK, let's see who's using it:

```
$ lsof mountpoint/
COMMAND  PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
bash    9244   pi  cwd    DIR   8,17     4096    2 mountpoint
```

So, there is a bash process running, with a PID of `9244`, owned by user `pi` and that is currently accessing the mountpoint. In this case, I have simply opened a terminal and `cd`ed into `mountpoint`.

All you need to do is stop that process. If you know what it is, just stop it. If you don't (and it is owned by you), you can `kill` it:

```
$ kill 9244
$ sudo umount mountpoint
$
```

And there you go, it worked!

Comment: Thanks for the `lsof` recommendation - what do you know, I was logged in under the folder I was trying to unmount in another terminal